# Discovery endpoint not found, Timeout exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm loading an host with a service called Service which implement the contract IService.
The binding is WSDualHttpBinding.

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService),new WSDualHttpBinding()
,endPointAddress);
```

In the client side i am trying to discover the endpoint.

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/Service/Client/Discovery", Environment.MachineName, "1111")));Environment.MachineName, 1111);
DiscoveryClient client =
new DiscoveryClient(new DiscoveryEndpoint(new WSDualHttpBinding(), address));
            FindResponse find = client.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(IService))
{ Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) });
```

It is not working... I get a timeout exception after a minute without any reason.
i am running the host and the client on the same machine.

does anyone can detect what the problem is?

thanks

Comment: Any possibility this is a typo in your code? "/Serviec/"

Comment: no sorry, it is not in my code, I edit the post

Comment: maybe you should add a "s" in the url http://{0}:{1}/Servie/Client/Discovery. you have written Servie in place of Service.

Comment: Any possibility your firewall is blocking UDP comms?

Comment: No, I use UDP in other programs and I don't have any problem... anyhow I don't use UDP here